# Update Buttons JavaFX when a selected process in TableView ends

Tags: button, javafx, tableview, refresh, listener

I want to disable/enable the buttons under the BorderPane when a process in selected row ends.

I try this

```
downloadTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndices().addListener(new ListChangeListener<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(Change<? extends Integer> c) {
            int selectedIndex = downloadTable.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex();
            if (downloadTable.getItems().get(selectedIndex).getStatus() == Download.DOWNLOADING) {
                cancelButton.setDisable(false);
            } else {
                cancelButton.setDisable(true);
            }

        }
    });
```

but it only works if I switch to an items (download) that is already ended.
What I want to do is to enable/disable buttons while an item is selected.
Thanks all

[example of ended download with cancelButton that I want to disable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D1xKf.png)

Comment: Can you show the model class for the table?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this can help you:

```
public class Main {

    private Button someButton;
    private TableView<?> downloadTable;

    private void someMethod() {
        //somecode
        Callback<TableView<?>, TableRow<?>> baseFactory = downloadTable.getRowFactory();
        downloadTable.setRowFactory( new CustomRowFactory<?>( someButton, baseFactory ) );
        //somecode
    }

}

public class CustomRowFactory<T> implements Callback<TableView<T>, TableRow<T>> {

    private final Callback<TableView<T>, TableRow<T>> baseFactory;
    private final Button someButton;

    public CustromRowFactory( Button someButton, Callback<TableView<T>, TableRow<T>> baseFactory) {
        this.someButton = somButton;
        this.baseFactory = baseFactory;
    }

    @Override
    public TableRow<T> call(TableView<T> tableView) {
        final TableRow<T> row = baseFactory == null ? row = new TableRow<>() : row = baseFactory.call( tableView );
        someButton.disableProperty().bind(
            row.selectedProperty().and( row.getItem().statusProperty().isNotEquals(Download.DOWNLOADING) )
        );
        return row;
    }

}
```

or insert binding in some of your `TableCell` implementation.